# Angle between two lines with same origin?

Tags: angle

I need to calculate angle between two line segments with the same origin.  One line is perpendicular to the y-axis.  Please suggest a method?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific. How are the two lines given?

Comment: well in what platform do you want it? and also in 2d or 3d?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two lines. `y=m1x+c1` and `y=m2x+c1`, lets say `l1` and `l2` respectively. If line `l1` is perpendicular to the `y` axis, it means that `l1` is parallel to `x` axis, so the slope of `l1` is 0. So the angle between `l1` and `l2` will be `arctan(m2)`.